# Solve $x = Cx+d$ for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Given
>
> $$C = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0.7 & 0.2 \\ 
> 0.1 & 0.5 \\ 
> \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad 
> d = \begin{bmatrix}
> 26\\
> 52\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Solve the equation $x = C x + d$ for $x$.

I'm a little confused as to why $x$ is on both sides of the equation. Am I supposed to find the determinant to solve this?

Update: I multiplied the identity matrix by matrix $C$. Then I multiplied this times $d$ to get $x$. Which gave me the answer:

\begin{bmatrix}
180\\
140\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Idea: Write your equation as $$(I-C)x=d$$ and then solve for $x$ as usual!

Comment: So $$\begin{align}
&  
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}x
-
\begin{bmatrix}
0.7 & 0.2 \\ 
0.1 & 0.5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} x
& = 
\begin{bmatrix}
26\\
52\\
\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$ ?

Comment: Yes! $$\begin{pmatrix} 0.3&0.2\\0.1&0.5 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 26\\52 \end{pmatrix}$$ and then find $a$ and $b$

Comment: sorry, $a_{12}=-0.2$ and $a_{21}=-0.1$

Comment: So then how do I solve for $$ a \text{ and }  b$$. Do I find the inverse of C and multiply that times d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Substitute $x=Ix=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}x$ and solve $$(C-I)x+d=0$$

Answer (score 1):

With $x=(u,v)$ the equation $x= Cx+d $ is equivalent to

$u=0.7u+0.2v+26$

$v=0.1u+0.5v+52.$

Can you take it from here?